# WTH - command not found - if statement - bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've seen posts similar to this, where the "command not found" error is thrown because of white space errors in the if statement.

I can't find my white space errors. Where are they? What else could it be?

Basically, if I run test.sh (below) without a flag, the terminal starts shouting rude obscenities like, "Command not found". If I use a flag, it plays nice. I don't want to bribe bash with flags all the time. It's not good for it's long term health.

This is in **test.sh**:

```
verbose='false'
aflag=''
bflag=''
sflag=''
files=''
while getopts 'absf:v' flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
        a) aflag='true';;
        b) blag='true' ;;
        s) sflag='true' ;;
        f) files="${OPTARG}" ;;
        v) verbose='true';;
        *) error "Unexpected option ${flag}" ;;
    esac
done

# ======= Below this is where the error gets thrown
if "$sflag" ;
then
  echo "okay" ;
fi
# ======= end error throwing code 

echo "end" # this prints just fine
```

I run the above script with

```
$ bash test.sh
```

and then I get back

```
test.sh: line 17: : command not found
end
```

Will someone please give me advice on how to talk bash into behaving rationally?

I'm using a Mac (I don't know if that makes a difference).

Comment: you compare to nothing the if, and if if is empty "there is no such command"

Comment: What are you trying to check for?  You can do `if [[ -n $sflag ]]; then` to check if the variable is not null or -z to check if it is.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any suggestions for re-implementation? That would be fantastical.

Comment: @Jesse_b just trying to check if the flag is true... is the empty string considered null in bash? if Not, I suppose I could do a check for length...

Comment: You could do `if [[ "$sflag" = "true" ]]; then`

Comment: I check emptyness using `if [ "x$flags" = x ]; then echo empty ; else echo not empty ; fi`

Comment: @Jesse_b yeah... that seems so sloppy though. I was hoping the falsy idea was relevant to bash :/

Comment: @Archemar I like that idea

Comment: @Archemar Why?  You should do `if [[ -n $flags ]]; then` from now on.  @Jill How is it sloppy?  It is checking for a particular result and therefore will have less chance of unexpected outcomes.  With your script you should be able to do `if [[ -n $sflag ]]; then` without an issue but I think that is sloppier because it will accept any non-null value as true.

Comment: @Archemar `if "x$sflag" = "x" `; and `if "x$sflag" = x `  isn't working for me anyway. **shrug** seemed clever in theory. Just says "x command not found". So @Jesse_b wins

Comment: use brackets...and better commands (the ones I suggested :p)

Comment: @Archemar (when I changed it to brackets it worked)

Comment: rather than set the flag variables to `'true'` or `'false'` so that you can run them to get the exit code, it's better to initialise them to `0` and have the getopts loop set them to `1`, then test them like `if [ "$sflag" == 1 ] ; then ... fi`.  Alternatively, set them to the empty string `''` and have getopts set them to anything.  then you can test if they're non-empty (`if [ -n "$sflag" ]; then ... fi`)

Comment: @cas I like the simplicity of that, although, I'd like to know your reasoning behind why it's better. Also, I'd still use terdon's `if "$sflag"` instead of if [ "$sflag" == 1 ] because that seems sloppy. If (true) is more elegant to me than if (true == true), which seems like extraneous, nutritionally devoid  calories.

Comment: because with the way you're doing it, you're running an external program (`/bin/true` or `/bin/false`) and then checking the exit code instead of just checking the value of a bash variable within bash.  i.e. fork and check vs just check.

Comment: @cas are you saying that setting variables to true or false causes an external program called /bin/true , /bin/false, to run, which isn't a part of bash? Are basically saying this is less efficient? How does it affect the call stack? Do you know? I'm basically asking how it would be less efficient -- not because I think you're wrong. I'm just curious.

Comment: @JillRussek `if x; then ... fi` runs command `x` and checks the exit-code.  `[` is an external command (`/usr/bin/[`), as is `test` (`/usr/bin/test`) ....it just so happens that `[` and `test` are **also** built-in to many modern shells (including bash) so there's no need to call an external program for them.   What this means is that `if "$sflag"; ...` actually runs the command specified by the value of `$sflag` (in this case, that will be either `true` or `false`).  So, yes, less efficient because it needs to run external commands.

Comment: @JillRussek i just ran across this Q again.   It turns out that `true` and `false` are also bash built-in commands (running `type true false` says they're built-in, and `help true false` describes them, and they're mentioned as built-ins in the bash man page).  This is also the case in other `sh`-like shells I tested - `dash`, `ash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` - huh, i never realised. i'll make use of this in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you are passing no flags, so the whole `while getopts` loop is never run, your `$sflag` remains empty and, as a result, what bash actually runs is:

```
if ""; then echo "okay" ; fi
```

The simplest solution would be to initialize your variables as false:

```
verbose='false'
aflag='false'
bflag='false'
sflag='false'
files='false'
while getopts 'absf:v' flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
        a) aflag='true';;
        b) blag='true' ;;
        s) sflag='true' ;;
        f) files="${OPTARG}" ;;
        v) verbose='true';;
        *) error "Unexpected option ${flag}" ;;
    esac
done

# ======= Below this is where the error gets thrown
if "$sflag" ;
then
  echo "okay" ;
fi
# ======= end error throwing code 

echo "end" # this prints just fine
```